# Pagination doesn't works on my Django App as expected

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to paginate, it shows in the address bar that I'm on page 2 but nothing new gets displayed.

Below is an excerpt from my views.py looks:

```
class JobList(ListView):
    model               = Job
    template_name       = "jobs/job_listings.html"
    context_object_name = "job_list"
    ordering            = ['-published_date']
    paginate_by         = 3

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(JobList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        jobs_expiring_soon = Job.objects.filter(application_last_date__gte=datetime.now(), application_last_date__lte=lookup_date)
        state_list = State.objects.order_by('name')
        profession_list = Profession.objects.order_by('name')

        context['jobs_expiring_soon'] = jobs_expiring_soon
        context['state_list'] = state_list
        context['profession_list'] = profession_list

        return context
```

Below is an excerpt from my urls.py file:

```
path('', JobList.as_view(), name = 'job-list'),
```

Below is the associated template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block page_content %}

{% for job in job_list %}
<div class="listing-wrapper">
    <div class="listing-container border-top border-bottom">
        <a href="{{ job.get_absolute_url }}">
        <h2 class="heading mt-3 mb-1 mx-2 d-inline-block">{{ job.title|truncatechars:75 }}</h2>
        <p class="mx-2"><span class="sub-heading mr-1">Number of Posts:</span><span class="mr-1 ml-1">{{ job.nop }}</span>|<span class="sub-heading ml-1 mr-1">Last Date to Apply:</span><span>{{ job.application_last_date|date:"j-M-Y" }}</span></p>
        <p class="mx-2 mb-3">{{ job.summary|truncatechars:200 }}</p>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}

{% if is_paginated %}
<ul class="pagination justify-content-center my-4">
  {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
  <li class="page-item">
    <a class="page-link bg-dark text-white" href="?page{{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">&larr; Previous Page</a>
  </li>
  {% endif %}

  {% if page_obj.has_next %}
  <li class="page-item">
    <a class="page-link bg-dark text-white" href="?page{{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">Next Page &rarr;</a>
  </li>
  {% endif %}
</ul>
{% endif %}

{% endblock page_content %}
```

I would really grateful, if anyone could please help me in getting this fixed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have more than 3 jobs created?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `context_object_name = 'job'`. I believe `_list` gets appended to it automatically which would mean your current view generates the context `job_list_list`.